# My reverse lights stay on when truck is in park but won't come on when in reverse. What would it be.?

Tags: maintenance

1989 Chevrolet Scottsdale  pickup truck
The problem happened roughly one week ago.

Comment: Have you checked the switch for adjustment? Has it come loose? Manual or auto?

Comment: They did say "Park" which indicates an automatic.

Comment: @Moab try this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMJhOSdxQVg

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced any bulbs recently, ensure you didn't pop a single filament bulb into a double filament socket. This can cause the lights to ground out through the other bulbs and cause all sorts of erroneous behavior.